# Ec2 Amazon virtual machine

Tags: amazon-ec2

I have a problem.
I conjectured that there is no prime formed by the concatenation of two consecutive Mersenne numbers (examples are 157,12763,40952047...) which is congruent to 6 mod 7. Because  these numbers have the form (2^k-1)*10^d+2^(k-1)-1, it is easy to see that they growth very rapidly. I arrived to k=565.000 and no prime 6 mod 7 was found. Now I would continue the search at least upto k=1 million and I thought that Amazon ec2 virtual machine could be the solution. What do you suggest, what package should I buy?

Answer (score 1):

Aws provide virtual machines with EC2 services.

For such specific problem, I think you will have to write the program by yourself, even if you have specific server type for computing (like your problem)

Comment: Can I use Pfgw with the virtual machine? Pfgw is a program for primality checking

Comment: I don't know this program but it seems to be available on linux/windows, for X86 cpu. EC2 can be run with these two OS.